# NVIDIA-T400 GPU not giving output

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I have a system with the following details:
[image: System Details]

I got a new NVIDIA-T400 GPU and installed it on the motherboard. But I get a blank screen when I try to channel my video output through the NVIDIA GPU. I am not even able to access the BIOS. But if I keep the GPU plugged into the motherboard but route the output through the inbuilt graphics card and execute the following command, `lspci | grep VGA`, I get the following output:

[image: command output with GPU installed]

The output of the same command if the GPU is not connected is

[image: command output without GPU]

Could anybody please help in resolving this issue?
Let me know if I need to give more details.